# When memory is low, does android destroy individual activities or the entire stack?

Tags: android

Like the title says, what exactly happens when android runs low on memory? Does it randomly pick and choose activities and just kill them off or does it kill off entire back stack of an app.

I am worried that the history of my activities in my app will not be preserved properly (e.g. profile page coming before edit picture page)

Comment: AFAIK it kills the whole process. So your app will be killed as a whole

Comment: @ShobhitPuri care to provide some sources and post your answer as a response so I can accept it properly?

Comment: Just added an answer with 2 sources. Hope it clarifies your question. Those links to documentation have more details which you can go through.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It kills the whole process and not just some activities. Your app will be killed as a whole, if OS decides to kill the process in which your app in running.

If you go through [Processes and Application Lifecycle](https://developer.android.com/guide/components/activities/process-lifecycle.html)

> In most cases, every Android application runs in its own Linux process. This process is created for the application when some of its code needs to be run, and will **remain running until it is no longer needed and the system needs to reclaim its memory for use by other applications**.

Also if you go through [Processes and Threads](https://developer.android.com/guide/components/processes-and-threads.html)

> By default, all components of the same application run in the same process and most applications should not change this.
>   ...
>   **Android might decide to shut down a process at some point, when memory is low and required by other processes that are more immediately serving the user.**

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 1):

System does not bother separate Activities but will kill the whole processes when it decides its the right way to reclaim some resources.  This will also affect process' Activities which will be gone too.